# Why are dependency properties "static"?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

Could someone please explain why dependency properties are declared as static ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The field you declare as static is only the *identifier* of a dependency property, not the *value* of the property. It is shared across all instances of the class, and is used to get/set the value of the property for each instance.

Comment: I have some requirement of making the DP as static because i want to shared it across all instances. Is it possible?

Comment: @RV1987, it doesn't really make sense... if you want to do that, don't use a DP, just use a static CLR property

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Seriously I cannot understand the meaning or justification of your statements what you are trying to say. I am newbie though and do not understand your words. Why we should set value for every instance if it is static. Static means its one time invokation throughout the program lifetime right.

Comment: @Divine, I'm not sure I understand your question... A dependency property is defined by an identifier field (e.g. `TextBox.TextProperty`), which is static. To get the value of the property for a given instance, you call `GetValue(TextProperty)` on the instance; to make things easier, most DPs have an instance property that acts as a shortcut (e.g. `TextBox.Text`)

Comment: BTW, downvoting my answer just because you don't understand it not very useful...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: I up voted it again :) However it is saying, my vote is locked. I di not know what to do.  Well I am afraid I didn't still understand anything. However, I will give some reading through some videos too. Thanks buddy for help.

Comment: Could you, please, explain also why dependency property is shared across all instances of the class? I can't imagine how it possibly can be useful. Isn't it encapsulation violation?

Comment: @havekar, my answer already explains it... it's not the property that is static, it's the *identifier* of the property; each instance has a its own value, of course. Dependency properties are a mechanism completely different from "normal" CLR properties; they enable scenarios like binding, animations, etc. And it has nothing to do with encapsulation.

Answer (score 14):

When you declare a `DependencyProperty`, you are declaring the *definition* of that property, rather than the storage space for the property's value (as would be the case with the regular property declaration).  There is only one definition of the property for the whole class - as opposed to one definition per instance of the class - and so it is static.

Comment: Any object with a `DependencyProperty` derives from type `DependencyObject`. An instance of `DependencyObject` includes a property bag - essentially a dictionary of property name mapped to value - and the value of any `DependencyProperty` that is set is stored in that bag.