# Why Dependency property are declared as static readonly?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

It is clear to me why dependency property are static and the question still remain on my mind is why we need to use Readonly keyword at the time of declaration of Dependency Property.

Comment: just have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989431/why-dependency-properties-are-static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually a dependency property is something that a dependency object simply has and that does not depend on when you use the property.  Just like a CLR property, if you ask does this object have a `Total` property, you know it cannot be a `double` now but an `int` later.  As a result, we'd make the dependency property `const` if we could, but we cannot, so `readonly` is the next best thing.

Using the `readonly` keyword has at least three effects:

- it informs readers of the code that the value will not change
- it prevents the author from accidentally changing the value
- it assists the compiler, which benefits from knowing when things will not change

Comment: yep, understood. but if I declare it not as read only, and I do want to change this property dynamically at run time for some reason, is that possible ? or for this scenario there's better solutions ?

Comment: The `readonly` here only relates to the Dependency Property Identifier, that ends in the word `Property`. This does NOT mean that the value of the Dependency Property cannot change. It is only this identifier that cannot change. This Dependency Property Identifier is used as part of a key in the `DependencyObject` class to get and set the actual values of the property.

Answer (score 2):

Because it makes it obvious, that the value of this property cannot be changed after initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this would help: [Silverlight.net forums: DependencyProperty - public static readonly?](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/209071/491856.aspx)

To quote:

> The "public static readonly" is the field that comes back from the Register call. The field is the identifier for the property. You only really need the identifier so that the Silverlight property system knows what to do, and so that you can use the property system yourself as you define the dependency property's CLR "wrapper". Once you have the wrapper, all further usage of the property can just use it like a typical property.
>
> Public so that all property system calls including cross-assembly can access it.
>
> Static and readonly because this isn't a definition that should ever change; the property system needs to get consistent results.
>
> In the attached property case, you want there to be an "owner" class. The owner class must be the class that calls RegisterAttached, AND must also define the static accessor methods (Get* and Set*) so that the XAML parser knows what to do when you try to set the attached property on a DependencyObject instance. So it's a little different, because for an attached property there usually isn't a "wrapper", any code access just uses the Get* and Set* accessors.