# How WPF DependencyProperty pickup the key to distinguish each instance of an object and seek the values of the DependencyProperty?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

From google, a lot of articles said that DependencyProperty is static because it has a KeyValue mechanism to maintain the value of each instance of the object.

But the problem is that, if we call GetValue / SetValue against the DependencyProperty, how does it identify each instance and generate the key so as to read / save the values from the HashTable for different instance of the object?

For example: if we create 2 instance of TestDp and then set value for TestDProperty of both instances, how does SetValue identify each instance and save the DependencyProperty value into the hash table accordingly?

I've checked the code for GetValue & SetValue of DependencyObject, but I still cannot figure out how it distinguish each instance. The code this.LookupEntry(dp.GlobalIndex) will pickup the EntryIndex but I'm not sure how the GlobalIndex is generated to distinguish each instance of the object.

```
 public class TestDp : DependencyObject
    {
        protected static DependencyProperty dpTest = DependencyProperty.Register("TestDProperty", typeof(string), typeof(TestDp));
        public string TestDProperty
        {
            get
            {
                var r = (string)GetValue(dpTest);
                return r;
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(dpTest, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but you call `GetValue`/`SetValue` on current instance of `DependencyObject`. Also `dpTest` should be named `TestDProperty` and CLR wrapper should be called `TestD` and name of registered property _"TestD"_

Comment: ***set value for TestDProperty of both instances*** when you do this, you of course have to call the `SetValue` on ***different instances***, so it knows where to save the data separately. Note that the data are shared only when they have the ***default value***, once they change for some specific instance, they will no longer be shared.

Comment: I've checked the code for GetValue & SetValue of DependencyObject, but I still cannot figure out how it distinguish each instance. The code this.LookupEntry(dp.GlobalIndex) will pickup the EntryIndex but I'm not sure how the GlobalIndex is generated to distinguish each instance of the object.

Comment: @mind1n `DependencyProperty` definition is static but  `this.GetValue(...)` and `this.SetValue(...)` are **instance methods of `DependencyObject`** so will be called on current instance just as `this.LookupEntry(...)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441453/why-dependency-properties-in-wpf-has-to-be-static and http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetValue of DependencyObject will call GetValueEntry and consume the EntryIndex which you've mentioned.  However, it doesn't seems to generate any key based on the instance information.

Comment: Right, there is only a global index for each DP, generated at the time the property is registered.  This serves as the 'key'.  There is no instance-specific key.

Answer (score 0):

Abbreviations used:

**DP**=`DependencyProperty`

**dp#**=DP instances, e.g, DP1

**DO**=`DependencyObject`

**dp#**=DO instances

Good good question, but I don't think the accepted answer and comments really got what you're asking, what a pity. A more clarified question might be:

**How a DependencyObject instance stores its local DependencyProperty(s) and retrieves it(them) by `GetValue` and `SetValue`?**

According to your description, you're on the write way to explore out the way, what you should do is to track down the source code a little bit more:

[DependencyObject.SetValue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,164)

[DependencyObject.GetValue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,417)

Before digging into details, bear in mind that one of the advantages the dependency mechanism offers is helping to [Reduced memory footprint](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html). So you can roughly imagine how it works: at the very beginning, each DO instance  has zero local DPs; and once it set a local DP by invoking the according `SetValue`, it allocates some space in memory to store it. Although the description is far from the truth, at least it gives you a preliminary grasp.

## DependencyProperty

First, let's focus on the DP. As we know, each DP *instance* will be registered **only once**, and DP has a private *static* field `int GlobalIndexCount`, which increments by 1 each time a new DP instance is registered. Accordingly, each DP **instance** has a `GlobalIndex`, a possible example might be as:

| DP instances | GlobalIndex |
| --- | --- |
| dp1 | 0 |
| dp2 | 1 |
| dp3 | 2 |

| Current static field GlobalIndexCount for DP |
| --- |
| 3 (which will be assigned to next registered DP instance) |

Btw, all DP instances are maintained by `Hashtable PropertyFromName` which is also a static field of class `DependencyProperty`. Bear in mind that each DP class instantiates only once.

## DependencyObject

Second, let's have a look at DO. Each DO instance maintains an array: `private EffectiveValueEntry[] _effectiveValues;` which stores all the **local** DP instances it needs. `EffectiveValueEntry` has two properties:

1. `PropertyIndex`: exactly GlobalIndex of a specific DP instance
2. `Value`: the local value of the DP setted by `SetValue`

Suppose we have a DO class defined as below:

```cs
// Keep declaration only and omit trivial code
public class MyDependencyObject : DependencyObject
{
  protected static DependencyProperty Test1Property;
  protected static DependencyProperty Test2Property;
  protected static DependencyProperty Test3Property;
}

MyDependencyObject do1...;
do1.Test1 = 1;
do1.Test3 = 3;
MyDependencyObject do2...;
do2.Test2 = 2;
```

Now `_effectiveValues` in `do1` looks like this

| EntryIndex.Index | PropertyIndex (equiv. GlobalIndex for DP), sorted | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | Local value for Test1Property |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | Local value for Test3Property |

where `EntryIndex` is returned by the function `LookupEntry` you mentioned. For situation in do2:

| Entry index | PropertyIndex (equiv. GlobalIndex for DP), sorted | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Local value for Test2Property |

All the `EffectiveValueEntry` stored in `_effectiveValues` are sorted by `GlobalIndex`

## The keypoint

**Now it comes to the core of you puzzle**: when a DO instance tries to get a DP, it use the DP's `GlobalIndex` to search its private field `_effectiveValues`, if found, a local DP value is returned; else, a default or inherited value is returned. Actually, the true story is much more complicated, see [Value resolution strategy](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html).

When it comes to *write* instead of *read*, similar stories happen, only by not reading but modifying `_effectiveValues`.